# Are there any close analogues to the Fairy King & Queen Titania and Oberon, in Indian/Hindu mythology?

Tags: comparative, hindu, fairies, india

I am looking to create a version of Titania & Oberon, the Queen & King of the Fairies in Midsummer Night's Dream, that would have context in India. Probably deities or mythological beings associated with nature/forests, but maybe with a tradition of meddling with humanity?  Thanks!

Comment: Oberon and Titania are simply characters in a play.  I take it you are referring to fairies generally.

Comment: I referred to Titania and Oberon as I want to create characters in a fiction that mirror them, but in an Indian mythological setting.  I am therefore looking for comparative Hindu deities/mythological beings that could fulfill similar roles.

Comment: I'd say Oberon & Titania are not entirely invented, but based on folk tradition, translated through the filter of the greatest writer in English.  Shakespeare's plays constitute a mythologies of their own, and it's important to remember that the Ancient Greek Dramatists were hugely important commentators and contributors to that mythological canon.

Comment: Are your characters good, wicked, or somewhere in-between?  The Shakespeare characters are fairly ambiguous.

Comment: DukeZhou ... I would say that they are flawed individuals like most of us... neither wicked nor good, but capable of actions that could be perceived as both.

Comment: @Maxine That is rather ambiguous. If you can give some sort of character sketch for both, I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: U could just create some

Comment: There are Rambha,Urvashi and Menaka for Aosaras

Comment: There are few for the Gandharvas too

Answer (score 2):

There is the Lore of the [Yaksha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaksha) & [Yakshini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakshini). As well as Kinnara & Kinnari.

Also Refer to a Tangential Piece of mine if you so feel.
[The Mythos of 'Yakshi'](https://wordpress.com/block-editor/post/themanwhoneverwasblog.wordpress.com/135)